# 'int android.view.View.getVisibility()' on a null object reference onphone but not in emulator

Tags: android

I am getting an java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getVisibility()' on a null object reference error when I load my app on my android marshmallow phone but it does not on the the avd emulator 
This question is diferent as the error only seems to occur on android 6.1 or lower.

AlarmReceiver.java

```
package com.example.ersch.noschoolcalculator;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String htmlContentInStringFormat;
private TextView Day1a;
private TextView Day1b;
private TextView Day1c;
private TextView Day2a;
private TextView Day2b;
private TextView Day2c;
private Boolean weather_gov_error;
private TextView ERROR_LOG;
private String first;
public Boolean fatal_error;
private String second;
private String day1a;
private String[] day1b;
private String day1c;
private String day2c;
private String day2a;
private String[] day2b;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private AlarmManager manager;
private String[] months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(14);
private Map<String, String> firstlist = new HashMap<>();
private Map<String, String> secondlist = new HashMap<>();
public static void longInfo(String str) {
    if(str.length() > 4000) {
        Log.i("Message:", str.substring(0, 4000));
        longInfo(str.substring(4000));
    } else
        Log.i("Message:", str);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //executes jsoup
    JsoupAsyncTask jsoupAsyncTask = new JsoupAsyncTask();
    jsoupAsyncTask.execute();
    //initializes layout

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Day1a = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Day1a);
    Day1b = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Day1b);
    Day1c = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Day1c);
    Day2a = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Day2a);
    Day2b = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Day2b);
    Day2c = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Day2c);
    ERROR_LOG = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ERROR_LOG);
    ERROR_LOG.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    //button click

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Refreshing", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            longInfo("Refreshing");
            JsoupAsyncTask jsoupAsyncTask = new JsoupAsyncTask();
            jsoupAsyncTask.execute();
        }

    });


}
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
public void startAlarm(View view) {
    manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int interval = 10000;

    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    longInfo("Alarm Set");
}
public void cancelAlarm(View view) {
    if (manager != null) {
        manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        longInfo("Alarm Canceled");
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public static boolean isListContainMethod(List<String> arraylist,String value) {
    for (String str : arraylist) {
        if (!str.toLowerCase().contains(value)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
public class JsoupAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            String loginFormUrl = "https://www.snowdaycalculator.com/Account/login.php";
            String loginActionUrl = "https://www.snowdaycalculator.com/prediction.php?zipcode=10562&snowdays=0&extra=0&";
            String email = "erschmny@gmail.com";
            String passinstr = "email";
            String password = "ltlake66";
            HashMap<String, String> cookies = new HashMap<>();
            HashMap<String, String> formData = new HashMap<>();
            Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(loginFormUrl).method(Connection.Method.GET).execute();
            Document loginDoc = loginForm.parse(); // this is the document that contains response html
            cookies.putAll(loginForm.cookies());
            formData.put("passInstr", "password");
            formData.put("email", email);
            formData.put("password", password);
            formData.put("back", "");
            Connection.Response homePage = Jsoup.connect(loginActionUrl)
                    .cookies(cookies)
                    .data(formData)
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .execute();


            htmlContentInStringFormat = homePage.parse().html();
            //longInfo(htmlContentInStringFormat);
            String[] lines = htmlContentInStringFormat.split("\\r?\\n");
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(theChance\\[)[0-9]{5,11}] = -?\\d*\\.?\\d+E*\\+*\\d*;");
            int x = 0;
            for( int i = 0; i < lines.length - 1; i++) {
                Matcher m = p.matcher(lines[i]);
                if (m.find()) {
                    if (x == 0) {
                        first = lines[i];
                        x += 1;
                    }
                    else{
                        second = lines[i];
                    }
                }

            }
            longInfo(first);
            if (first != null & second != null){
                String regex = "[0-9]{8,11}";
                Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(first);
                if (m.find()) {
                    firstlist.put("date",Long.toString(Math.round(Double.parseDouble(m.group()))));
                }
                String regex2 = "-?\\d*\\.?\\d*;";
                Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile(regex2).matcher(first);
                if (m2.find()) {
                    firstlist.put("chance",Long.toString(Math.round(Double.parseDouble(m2.group().substring(0, m2.group().length()-1)))));

                }
                String regex3 = "[0-9]{8,11}";
                Matcher m3 = Pattern.compile(regex3).matcher(second);
                if (m3.find()) {
                    secondlist.put("date",Long.toString(Math.round(Double.parseDouble(m3.group()))));
                }
                String regex4 = "-?\\d*\\.?\\d*;";
                Matcher m4 = Pattern.compile(regex4).matcher(second);
                if (m4.find()) {
                    secondlist.put("chance",Long.toString(Math.round(Double.parseDouble(m4.group().substring(0, m2.group().length()-1)))));
                }

                sb.setLength(0);
                day1a = firstlist.get("date");
                day1b = day1a.split("(?!^)");
                sb.append(day1b[0]).append(day1b[1]).append(day1b[2]).append(day1b[3]);
                firstlist.put("year", sb.toString());
                sb.setLength(0);
                sb.append(day1b[4]).append(day1b[5]);
                firstlist.put("month", sb.toString());
                sb.setLength(0);
                sb.append(day1b[6]).append(day1b[7]);
                firstlist.put("day", sb.toString());
                longInfo(firstlist.toString());


                day2a = secondlist.get("date");
                day2b = day2a.split("(?!^)");
                sb.setLength(0);
                sb.append(day2b[0]).append(day2b[1]).append(day2b[2]).append(day2b[3]);
                secondlist.put("year", sb.toString());
                sb.setLength(0);
                sb.append(day2b[4]).append(day2b[5]);
                secondlist.put("month", sb.toString());
                sb.setLength(0);
                sb.append(day2b[6]).append(day2b[7]);
                secondlist.put("day", sb.toString());
                longInfo(secondlist.toString());
                htmlContentInStringFormat = homePage.parse().html();
                lines = htmlContentInStringFormat.split("\\r?\\n");
                p = Pattern.compile("(1.5em\">)|(0.85em\")");
                x = 0;
                for( int i = 0; i < lines.length - 1; i++) {
                    m = p.matcher(lines[i]);
                    if (m.find()) {
                        if (x == 0) {
                            first = lines[i];
                            longInfo(first);
                            x += 1;
                        }
                        else{
                            second = lines[i];
                            longInfo(second);
                        }
                    }

                }
                regex = ">[A-z0-9, %]{2,1000}";
                m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(first);
                sb.setLength(0);
                while (m.find()) {
                    sb.append(m.group());
                }
                String temp = sb.toString();
                temp = temp.replaceAll(">","");
                temp = temp.replaceAll("T","t");
                firstlist.put("message",temp);
                longInfo(firstlist.get("message"));


                regex = ">[A-z0-9, %]{2,1000}";
                m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(second);
                sb.setLength(0);
                while (m.find()) {
                    sb.append(m.group());
                }
                temp = sb.toString();
                temp = temp.replaceAll(">","");
                temp = temp.replaceAll("T","t");
                secondlist.put("message",temp);
                longInfo(secondlist.get("message"));
            }
            else{
                p = Pattern.compile("<b>Fatal error<\\/b>[A-z :()<>/.0-9]*");
                x = 0;
                for( int i = 0; i < lines.length - 1; i++) {
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(lines[i]);
                    if (m.find()) {
                        if (x == 0) {
                            fatal_error = Boolean.TRUE;
                            x += 1;
                            longInfo(fatal_error.toString());
                        }
                        else{
                            longInfo("Extra fatal error data received");
                        }
                    }

                }
                p = Pattern.compile("\\/\\*\\*\\/\\/\\*Error[\\*={'\"#!;}A-z :()<>/.0-9]*");
                //not verified working
                x = 0;
                for( int i = 0; i < lines.length - 1; i++) {
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(lines[i]);
                    if (m.find()) {
                        if (x == 0) {
                            weather_gov_error = Boolean.TRUE;
                            x += 1;
                            longInfo(weather_gov_error.toString());
                        }
                        else{
                            longInfo("Extra weather.gov error data received");
                        }
                    }

                }

            }





        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (first != null & second != null){
            Day1a.setText(months[Integer.parseInt(firstlist.get("month")) - 1] + " " + firstlist.get("day") + ", " + firstlist.get("year"));
            if (Integer.parseInt(firstlist.get("chance")) <= 0) {
                Day1b.setText("Low");
            }
            else{
                Day1b.setText(firstlist.get("chance") + "%");
            }
            Day1c.setText(firstlist.get("message") + ".");
            Day2a.setText(months[Integer.parseInt(secondlist.get("month")) - 1] + " " + secondlist.get("day") + ", " + secondlist.get("year"));
            if (Integer.parseInt(secondlist.get("chance")) <= 0) {
                Day2b.setText("Low");
            }
            else{
                Day2b.setText(secondlist.get("chance") + "%");
            }
            Day2c.setText(secondlist.get("message") + ".");
        }
        else {
            Day1a.setText("Error");
            Day1b.setText("Error");
            Day1c.setText("Error");
            Day2a.setText("Error");
            Day2b.setText("Error");
            Day2c.setText("Error");
            if (fatal_error) {
                ERROR_LOG.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ERROR_LOG.setText("Website: Fatal Error");
            }
            else {
                ERROR_LOG.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if (weather_gov_error) {
                ERROR_LOG.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ERROR_LOG.setText("Website: Weather Error");
            }
            else {
                ERROR_LOG.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

cell_shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape= "rectangle"  >
<solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
<stroke android:width="1dp"  android:color="#000000"/>
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.ersch.noschoolcalculator.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_popup_sync"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    app:rippleColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
```

contnt_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.ersch.noschoolcalculator.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
<TableRow
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:text="Date"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:paddingStart="10dip"
        android:paddingEnd="10dip"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:text="Chance"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:paddingStart="10dip"
        android:paddingEnd="10dip"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:text="Message"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:paddingStart="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingEnd="10dip"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:paddingStart="10dip"
        android:paddingEnd="10dip"
        android:id="@+id/Day1a"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:paddingStart="10dip"
        android:paddingEnd="10dip"
        android:id="@+id/Day1b"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:paddingStart="10dip"
        android:paddingEnd="10dip"
        android:id="@+id/Day1c"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:paddingStart="10dip"
        android:paddingEnd="10dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/Day2a"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:paddingStart="10dip"
        android:paddingEnd="10dip"
        android:id="@+id/Day2b"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:paddingStart="10dip"
        android:paddingEnd="10dip"
        android:id="@+id/Day2c"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</TableRow>

<TextView
    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:paddingStart="10dip"
    android:paddingEnd="10dip"
    android:id="@+id/ERROR_LOG"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start Alarm"
    android:onClick="startAlarm" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cancel Alarm"
    android:onClick="cancelAlarm" />
```

Android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.ersch.noschoolcalculator">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

error message

```
                                --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.ersch.noschoolcalculator, PID: 2203
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getVisibility()' on a null object reference
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.forceUniformHeight(LinearLayout.java:1380)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1368)
                  at android.widget.TableRow.onMeasure(TableRow.java:114)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                  at android.widget.TableLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(TableLayout.java:464)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                  at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:476)
                  at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:439)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:703)
                  at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                  at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1367)
                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:768)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
I/Message::  theChance[20170219] = -1;  //PREDICTION
I/Message:: {day=19, date=20170219, month=02, chance=-1, year=2017}
I/Message:: {day=20, date=20170220, month=02, chance=-1, year=2017}
Application terminated.
```

Comment: In my case the problem was a view/control having the same id as another layout's control.

Answer (score 1):

This simply means the View was not inflated. Essentially you have set up a condition where you are depending on the View to get inflated (in the onCreate method for instance) before the callback is called. You cannot do that, and in general, you cannot predict on a real phone which case will occur. It could even happen that on the same phone, your code works 50% of the time. Essentially you need to delay calling the callback until after everything is created.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me but I am not sure exactly what I should fix. What am I calling before I inflate the view and how do you advise I delay the callback.

Comment: The error message should tell you the exact line where the problem is if you look at the whole thing

Comment: the error message does not reference any of my code at all.

Comment: Please post the full error message

Comment: I have posted the full error message.

Comment: Hmmm. The error doesnt scream anything obvious to me. But due to the fact that the error is due to a view not being instantiated, it seems more than likely that your receiver is getting called before the Activity is fully inflated, which then somehow is triggered behavior that depends on one of your views.  To check whether that is the case, try registering you receiver in the onResume method instead of onCreate. I would guess that that will solve your problem, but the error doesnt point to a clear source (at least from my poing of view)

Comment: I tried to do that but the problem persists. I have updated the code and error message above. I still have no clue what the problem is.

Comment: Then the next thing i would try is to see if the error persists if you switch to regular activity,  not an appcompat one.  Perhaps there is something that you have in your xml that is buggy in appcompat.

Comment: I tried making that change but the problem persists. The interesting thing is that this problem only occurs on android 6.1 or lower.

Comment: Aha... now you are getting somewhere. This strongly suggests that you are compiling with a high API (> 6.1) and using some feature in the code that is only for >6.1 API devices. The easiest way to track these problems is to reduce the build api to the minimum one you want to consider. When you do that, the place where the code is failing should be marked as an error if you are using a function that is not available in the lower api.

Comment: It results in this error: Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.

Comment: Hmm there seem to be a lot of other Stackeroverflow questions addressing that problem